# I can show my Folders in Windows8, but I can't in Ubuntu, Why?

Tags: partitioning, mount, windows-8

I have installed Windows8, then I installed Ubuntu 12.10, all partitions are appeared well in Windows8 & Ubuntu.

I have C which have Windows8 system, and (D & E) as an extended partitions
and Ubuntu two partitions (File-system & Swap)

I can see folders in all partitions but I can't in D (in Ubuntu)

When I want Folders in D, I must restart PC to open windows8

Can you tell me why? How can I solve it?

thanks :)

Comment: What filesystem is partition `D`? For NTFS you might want to install https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS-3G. NTFS read support should be default, but maybe it didn't install correctly.

Comment: Can you please share with us the output of the following commands: `sudo fdisk -l` `sudo mount`?

Comment: here; http://bit.ly/Zp1FLU

Answer (score -1):

You need to mount the partitions, they might be in the side bar of your file browser, or you may have to do it through the terminal like so:

```
sudo mkdir /media/mountpoint
sudo mount /dev/sdaPartiton Number here /media/mountpoint
```

and when you're done

```
sudo umount /media/mountpoint
```

Comment: Having some more information from the OP would be nice before telling him that this needs to be done. At the moment from all we know his disk might be on the other side of the world. This might be, or not a solution.